# what is the meaning of the lost+found directory on linux

Tags: linux, permissions

Most likely a rather obvious question but nevertheless I am doubtful about it. For development purpose our team got an linux VM tot work on. Once in a while I met a `lost+found` directory. Most of the time it is not accessible (permission denied). What is the meaning of this directory. Has it been implemented by Linux or has it been manually by one of the administrators?

I do agree with @Arcturus-B and I put some effort in it to get some extra informatie. I found info at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18154/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-lostfound-folder-in-linux-and-unix and http://www.linuxnix.com/2012/12/lostfound-directory-linuxunix.html I guess I was a little bit cautious and did expect to find so much detailed information about this.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? If you downvote, have the courtesy to explain way.

Comment: I did not downvote, but I can understand why: this is the kind of information that is *really* easy to find using any search engine.

Comment: I think It is not an enough reason..

Comment: Since the answer raises so much response it is probably an interesting item for more people.

Comment: @ridi Sorry for the resurrect, but thank you for asking this question. I was wondering the same, and your question + the answer was the first thing that popped up in my search engine.
Dear god, someone asked a newb questions... This forum is a joke.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files that are being open when an unexpected shutdown occurs may be damaged. On the following power up, the `fsck` tool is run to try to recover them. If any file is to be recovered, it is placed in the `lost+found` directory of the partition the original was stored in.

Comment: That must be the reason for that particular dir. I guess only `root` can access it?